# How to run custom JavaScript code on gallery attachment image selection

Tags: gallery, media, media-library

On line 4620 of media.views.js is this:

```
media.view.Attachment = media.View.extend({
  .....
  select: function( model, collection ) {
     .....
```

I would like to add some more features to this "select" function without editing this core file.

I have successfully extended the gallery render function with this:

```
media.view.Settings.Gallery = media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
   render: function() {
      ... my custom gallery render code here
```

but cannot get it working for media.view.Attachment

Could somebody show me how to `alert('here');` once a gallery image has been selected inside WordPress?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post an example of what you have tried with `media.view.Attachment`? It will be easier to understand why it doesn't work.